How to determine the grid coordinates in the DOM inside a cell editor?
I'm writring a cell editor that displays a dropdown list, which should normally display in a downward direction unless there is not enough room in which case it should display in an upward direction. I am able to get the coordinates of the cell by way of the eGridCell property but I am trying to figure the best way of getting the grid coordinates.
I could use @ViewChild to access the grid element and pass this to the cell editor - but it seems like there should be a better way that avoids this dependency. Any suggestions would be appreciated!
  agInit(params: ICellEditorParams): void {

    const eGridCell:HTMLElement = params.eGridCell; 
    const dOMRect:DOMRect = eGridCell.getBoundingClientRect(); 

    // how to get DOMRect of containing grid? 
  } 

